# Cómo guardar una salida de comando bash en variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

Necesito poder guardar una salida de un comando en una variable para luego poder utilizarla. Actualmente, estoy haciendo así pero no funciona:

```
nuevaExtension = $(awk 'NR=='$contador $directorio)
echo $nuevaExtension
```

No logro saber cómo es la sintaxis para almacenar la salida del comando anterior.

Answer (score 9):

Tal y como han comentado anteriormente otros usuarios, lo correcto es decir:

```
var=$(comando)
```

No me queda claro qué quieres hacer con `awk 'NR=='$contador $directorio` pero probablemente quieres escribir por pantalla la línea dada en la variable `$contador`. Para ello, es recomendable usar [`-v`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#Options) para pasar los parámetros:

```
awk -v numero_linea="$contador" 'NR==numero_linea' "$directorio"
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### ¿Qué errores tiene tu intento?

- En `nuevaExtension = $(awk 'NR=='$contador $directorio)`:

Nótese que cuando dices `var = $(comando)` lo que estás haciendo es intentar ejecutar el comando `var` con dos parámetros: `=` y `$(comando)`.

```
$ var = $(ls)
var: command not found
```

- En `echo $nuevaExtension`

Deberías acostumbrarte a utilizar comillas dobles cuando usas `echo`, pues de lo contrario el formato se pierde:

```
$ v="hola
> que tal"
$ echo $v
hola que tal   # ¿dónde está el salto de línea?
$ echo "$v"
hola           # ¡bien! se conserva el salto de línea
que tal
```

Answer (score 4):

Te recomiendo que guardes también lo que retorna `stderr` porque si el comando arroja error no te estarías enterando.

```
var=$(comando 2>&1)
```

Solo `stdout`

```
var=$(comando)
```

Luego usa las comillas en el `echo` así te respeta los saltos de linea.

```
echo="$var"
```

**Ejemplo**

No respeta saltos de línea:

```
:~$ var=$(ps)
:~$ var=$(ps); echo $var
PID TTY TIME CMD 5516 pts/701 00:00:00 bash 21454 pts/701 00:00:00 ps
```

Respeta los saltos de línea:

```
:~$ var=$(ps); echo "$var"
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5516 pts/701  00:00:00 bash
21743 pts/701  00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: `var = $(comando)` es incorrecto, no entiendo su mención en la respuesta.

Comment: lo he probado en una terminal @fedorqui, por que decís que es incorrecto?

Comment: Que se ejecute no quiere decir que sea correcto. En [mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26954/83) detallo qué pasa al ejecutar este comando. Básicamente, con `var = $(comando)` ejecutar el comando `var` con dos parámetros `=` y `$(comando). Por tanto, la variable no se define.

Comment: var no es un comando compañero, y no entiendo porque no es correcto. Busco documentación y me encuentro por todos lados que así se hace. Pero acepto lo que dices.

Comment: Eso es lo que estoy diciendo yo: si quieres asignar a la variable `$var` el resultado del comando `command`, debes decir `var=$(command)`. Lo que decía tu respuesta antes de que la editaras ahora mismo es `var = $(command)`, que intentaría ejecutar `var` como si fuera un comando, pasándole los parámetros `=` y `$(command)`. Es decir, una cosa absolutamente distinta.

Comment: hubiéramos empezado por ahí, gracias por hacérmelo notar, si  tienes razón fue un error de tipeo y tenés razón.

Comment: Faltaría más : ) +1 por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con:

```
OUTPUT="$(ls -l)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

Comment: mejor no usar nombres de variable en mayúscula, pues pueden colisionar con las variables de entorno y liártela

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba lo mismo, ya vi cual es el error
Tú pones

```
nuevaExtension = $(awk 'NR=='$contador $directorio)
echo $nuevaExtension
```

y es:

```
nuevaExtension=$(awk 'NR=='$contador $directorio)
echo $nuevaExtension
```

Es decir, no debe tener espacio a los lados del ***'='***

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la pregunta ya tiene mucho tiempo, todavía puedo contribuir con algo que se me hizo algo interesante.

Almacenar el valor de un comando en una variable **pero como la salida de un pipeline**.

```
bash> set +m  # Para deshabilitar los jobs en backgroud
bash> shopt -s lastpipe  # Para correr el último comando de
                     # un pipeline en foreground

bash> echo "hola" | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" | read variable
bash> echo "$variable"
HOLA
```

Si estamos usando *ZSH*, la opción de correr el último comando en foreground (el actual ambiente de nuestra shell) viene por defecto. Así que nos podemos ahorrar todo el tecleo anterior:

```
zsh> echo "hola" | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" | read variable
zsh> echo "$variable"
HOLA
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo asi:

```
RUTA=$(pwd)
echo $RUTA;
```

te tira por consola: la ruta donde estas parado

Answer (score -1):

```
nuevaExtension=$(awk 'NR=='${contador}${directorio})

echo $nuevaExtension
```

Answer (score -1):

### A ver si te sirve esto:

`$ declare -a myarray`

`$ myarray=($(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd))`

`$ for item in "${!myarray[@]}"; do echo "${item} ${myarray[$item]}"; done`

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues contentos a tú respuesta, no solo el código con la solución, así el que hace la pregunta y otro visitante, no solo tienen la solución, sino que también aprenden a resolver casos similares, más no idénticos.