# ¿Cómo realizar un comando específico en PS1 Linux (programación en scripting?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, shell, línea-de-comandos

Resulta que estoy estudiando programación en scripting y tengo que hacer una pregunta donde me piden crear un PS1 personalizando el prompt de la terminal de manera que se vea el nombre de usuario, en el cual las vocales sean sustituidas por números (a = 1, e = 2, i = 3...), la fecha y la ruta actual. He estado buscando como personalizar el PS1 y he encontrado varias páginas donde especifican cómo se puede hacer esto. Sin embargo, no encuentro la manera poder sustituir las vocales del nombre de usuario por números y que estos se vean reflejados en el PS1. Por los apuntes que tengo, sé que una manera de sustituir las vocales por números sería:

```
tr aeiou 12345
usuario
5s51r34
```

Pero no sé cómo podría poner ese comando en el PS1 ya que según he visto la estructura para poner el usuario, fecha y ruta sería:

`PS1="\u \d \W"`

Lo que me devuelve:

`usuario lun oct 12 ~`

¿Alguien sabría cómo podría realizar el comando tr para que me haga la sustitución dentro de la personalización del PS1?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo guardar una salida de comando bash en variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25890/c%c3%b3mo-guardar-una-salida-de-comando-bash-en-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suoongo que podrias colocar algo como `PS1=$( echo -n hola soy $USER )`. Lo que haya dentro de `$( )` será ejecutado y se mostrará la salida como el prompt ... pero ese es un **educated guess** de mi parte. Un proyecto donde sé que hacen trucos de este tipo es bash-git-prompt. Échale un ojo a ver como lo hacen: https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt

Comment: Muchas gracias! No sabía que con el signo `$` podía ejecutar un comando dentro de PS1. Estoy comenzando en el tema de la programación y soy bastante novato. Gracias a que puedo ejecutar cualquier cosa dentro de `$()` he conseguido poner el formato tal cual me lo pide el ejercicio, ya que la fecha la quería en formato día/mes/año. Además, la ruta actual la he puesto con el comando `pwd` no con `"\u"`. De tal manera que finalmente he hecho lo siguiente: `PS1="$(tr aeiou 12345) - $(date +%d/%m/%Y) - $(pwd)`. El resultado que he obtenido: `dsc31lv1r4rp22 - 12/10/2020 - /home/dscialvarorp22`