# Dar un valor a una variable con sha256sum

Tags: bash, shell, sha256

Con las muy buenas gente, un abrazo a todos, tengo la siguiente duda: tengo una variable con el nombre de *password*, en la cual lo insertado quiero pasarlo con shasum a la variable *clave*.

- Obtengo la password:

  ```
  read -p "   Ingrese la password: " password
  ```
- Convierto a 256:

  ```
  clave = sha256sum
  ```

Lo que necesito, es saber cómo se puede plicar a una cadena un sha256 para *clave* obtenga el valor de *password* ya convertido en sha256.

Pienso algo así, pero clave no me toma el el valor de password encriptada:

```
clave=$password | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Eso en bash se haría con:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# A sample Bash script

password=""
read -p "Ingrese el password: " input
password="${input}"
echo "$password"
echo -n "$password" | sha256sum
echo "bye!"
```

Un ejemplo con Bash 4:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# A sample Bash script

password=""
read -e -i "$password" -p "Ingrese el password: " input
password="${input:-$password}"
echo "$password"
echo -n "$password" | sha256sum
echo "bye!"
```

Se puede usar `printf` en vez de `echo -n`

En ambos casos, la salida sería similar a

```
Ingrese el password: pepito
pepito
c8cdf720db5562a039be5d81c51a07c5120eaf0bf142b2144f1a1eb7a95678d3  -
bye!
```

Comment: eso estamos claros, pero como paso el valor de password ya codificado a la variable clave, porque con el echo solo lo muestro en la pantalla pero no se agrega a esa vriable

Comment: @dogdark con `variable=$(comando)`. Véase [Cómo guardar una salida de comando bash en variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25890/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' estás respondiendo con esa edición de la respuesta? :/

Comment: @Alfabravo mmm no, simplemente puse las comillas por precaución, pues se recomienda. No sé si entiendo tu comentario

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' estás editando mi respuesta con algo que consideras que le falta a la respuesta. Es un poco "burda" esa forma de recomendar un cambio en una respuesta que no es tuya. Es todo.

Comment: No es que sea algo que considere, sino que es algo prácticamente estándar (véase [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/1983854), por ejemplo) y que no creo burdo, sino bueno y que hago con frecuencia para mejorar esta gran biblioteca que es SO. No me meto en temas estilísticos, sino en temas de recomendar soluciones lo más completas posible, tal y como [la propia red recomienda](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120577/209901). En cualquier caso, si no te gusta le edición puedes revertirla, ningún problema.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Del FAQ: `Common reasons for edits include:
* To fix grammar and spelling mistakes, * To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning), * To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place, * To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages, * To add related resources or hyperlinks`. Ahí no entras porque es algo que es estándar y no lo puse. Y lo más interesante: la respuesta ni siquiera está completa porque hay algo que pidió el OP y que no se está haciendo.

Comment: Yo me centraría en la parte de _If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you_. Como dije, siéntete libre de revertir o tapar los oídos a lo que no quieras oír/aprender. Por mí, ningún problema. (spoiler: yo aprendí muchísimo de la gente que me editó en SO a lo largo de los años, inicialmente también me sorprendió y se me hizo raro pero con el tiempo incluso lo agradecí)

Comment: +1 por las comillas para evitar los problemas de seguridad y splitting documentados en Bash