# Cortar texto con CUT en bash

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, cut

Quisiera saber como puedo cortar una fracción de texto guardada en un archivo .dat y ponerla en una variable.

**Contenido de Archivo .dat**

```
texto
texto
File name: /home/paez/Documentos/Programas/RE/test/2021/05/12-1425-08L.F202105
texto
texto
```

Quiero que se guarde en un una variable **X** el fragmento desde **/home/..../12-1425-08L.F202105**

**Intente**

```
grep "/home" archivo.dat | cut -d/ -f2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

pero me sale en la terminal sin el primer **/** y me falta guardarlo en una variable

```
home/paez/Documentos/Programas/RE/test/2021/05/12-1425-08L.F202105
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo guardar una salida de comando bash en variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25890/c%c3%b3mo-guardar-una-salida-de-comando-bash-en-variable)

Comment: Respecto a lo que sugirió @fedorqui, es buena idea que por cada pregunta concreta, crees una publicación, y no una publicación con más de una pregunta. Así, "deacoplando las preguntas", incrementas el alcance de tus preguntas y sus respectivas respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí hay dos preguntas. Una es la de cómo obtener la ruta dentro de un archivo, y otra es de cómo almacenar la variable.

Para la primera ruta puedes intentar con `grep` y una expresión regular que olvida todo lo que está antes del primer slash:

```
$ grep -Po "\K/.*" archivo.dat
```

Otra opción es con el uso de `awk`:

```
$ awk '/\//{print $3}' archivo.dat
```

En el que tan solo busco por los registros que contengan diagonales, e imprimo lo que está después del segundo espacio; es decir, la ruta.

Ahora, refiriéndome a la segunda pregunta, para usar este resultado en una variable siempre es buena idea utilizar un *command substitution* y asignar eso a una variable:

```
$ ruta="$(grep -Po "\K/.*" archivo.dat)"
$ echo $ruta
/home/paez/Documentos/Programas/RE/test/2021/05/12-1425-08L.F202105
```

Aunque también puedes utilizar la opción *lastpipe* de bash, y asignar la salida a una variable:

```
$ set +m
$ shopt -s lastpipe
grep -Po "\K/.*" archivo.dat | read ruta
$ echo $ruta
/home/paez/Documentos/Programas/RE/test/2021/05/12-1425-08L.F202105
```

Esto sería más sencillo si usaras zsh:

```
zsh$ grep -Po "\K/.*" archivo.dat | read ruta
zsh$ echo $ruta
/home/paez/Documentos/Programas/RE/test/2021/05/12-1425-08L.F202105
```

También podrías usar una opción con las puras opciones de Bash:

```
while IFS=/ read _ _path
do
    if [ "$_path" ]; then
        echo "La ruta es: /$_path"
    fi
done < "archivo.dat"
```

Resultando en:

```
La ruta es: /home/paez/Documentos/Programas/RE/test/2021/05/12-1425-08L.F202105
```

Aquí sólo iteramos sobre las líneas del archivo con el `while`, luego  dividimos los campos asignando la variable IFS a "/", y entonces, con read, asignamos cada campo (¡Ahora separado por las diagonales!) como el primero (lo que no nos importa), y lo segundo (que es la ruta).

Ya dentro del while, si existe la ruta; es decir, si regresa algo diferente a la cadena vacía; entonces realiza lo que está dentro del `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar la salida de un comando (o varios, por ejemplo, si usas una tubería) en una variable, se usa `$( comando )`, por ejemplo:

```
salida=$( grep hola un-archivo )
echo $salida # mostraria lo que salió del grep
```